# A game of rock, paper, scissors made with ES2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, rock-paper-scissors

Please give me feedback on my code, on what you like and don't like. I tried to make use of ES2015 as much as I could. There is some jQuery in there as well. Any pro tips you can give me? Here is a demo of the game:

https://capozzic1.github.io/es2015-rock-scissors-paper/

Here is the javascript code:

```
let Module = (function (){

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.choice = null;
  }
  set points(num) {
    this.score = num;
  }

  set _choice(string) {
    this.choice = string;
  }
  //player chooses rock scissors or paper
  getPlayerInput() {

    let input = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
    for (let i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
      input[i].onclick = event => {

        let choice = event.target.dataset.tag;

        switch (choice) {
          case "rock":

            this.choice = "rock";

            break;
          case "scissors":
            this.choice = "scissors";
            break;
          case "paper":
            this.choice = "paper";
            break;
        }
        game.hideInfo();
        game.displayAnimation(this.choice, computer.choice);


      };
    }
  }

  //computer chooses rock, scissors, or paper
  getComputerInput() {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

    switch (randomNum) {
      case 1:
        this.choice = "rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        this.choice = "paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        this.choice = "scissors";
        break;

    }
  }
}
//A game class with some properties
class Game {

  constructor(round) {
    this.round = 1;
    this.animDone = false;
    this.gamePics = [
      'img/paper.png',
      'img/rock.png',
      'img/scissors.png'
    ];
  }
  //Compares input of player and computer
  compareInput() {


    let gameInterval = setInterval(() => {

    if (this.animDone == true) {
      switch (true){

        case player.choice == "rock" && computer.choice == "scissors":
          player.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Player wins!");
          break;

        case computer.choice == "rock" && player.choice == "scissors":
          computer.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Computer wins!");
          break;
        case player.choice == "paper" && computer.choice == "rock":
          player.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Player wins!");
          break;
        case computer.choice == "paper" && player.choice == "rock":
          computer.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Computer wins!");
          break;
        case player.choice == "scissors" && computer.choice == "paper":
          player.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Player wins!");
          break;
        case computer.choice == "scissors" && player.choice == "paper":
          computer.score += 1;
          game.displayWinner("Computer wins!");
          break;
        case computer.choice == "scissors" && player.choice == "scissors":
          game.displayWinner("It's a draw!");
          break;
        case computer.choice == "paper" && player.choice == "paper":
          game.displayWinner("It's a draw!");
          break;
        case computer.choice == "rock" && player.choice == "rock":
          game.displayWinner("It's a draw!");
          break;


          }
          //handle what to do after a player/computer wins
          game.round += 1;
          game.displayRound(game.round);
          game.displayScore(player.score, computer.score);
          clearInterval(gameInterval);
          game.animDone = false;
          game.checkWinner(player.score, computer.score);
          game.newRound();
        }

        }, 1000);

      }

      displayWinner(input){
        let span = document.querySelector(".g-winner");
        span.innerHTML = input;

      }

      displayScore(pscore,cscore){
        //set player's score to display in the span
        $('.p-score').html(pscore);
        //set computer's score to display in the span
        $('.c-score').html(cscore);
      }

      displayRound(round){

        $('.round').html(round);

      }

      displayAnimation(choice,compchoice){


        let img = document.querySelector(".p-anim");
        let img2 = document.querySelector(".c-anim");
        let input = choice;
        let input2 = compchoice;

        let counter = 0;

        let animInterval = setInterval(newPic, 700);
        let self = this;

        function newPic(){

          $('.p-anim, .c-anim').effect('shake', {direction:"up"}, {distance:30}, {times:3});
          img.src = self.gamePics[1];
          img2.src = self.gamePics[1];

          counter += 1;

          if (counter == 3){


            let [first, second] = self.lastAnimPic(input,input2);

            console.log(first,second,"test");
            img.src = game.gamePics[first];
            img2.src = game.gamePics[second];
            game.animDone = true;

            clearInterval(animInterval);

          }

        }

      }
      //this function returns an array that is used to set the last animation picture
      //to what the user or computer chose
      lastAnimPic(choice1,choice2) {

        let idxs = [];


        for (let i = 0, len = this.gamePics.length; i < len; i++){


          if (choice1 == choice2 && this.gamePics[i].indexOf(choice1) != -1){
            idxs[0] = i;
            idxs[1] = i;

          } else if (this.gamePics[i].indexOf(choice2) != -1){
            idxs[1] = i;


          } else if (this.gamePics[i].indexOf(choice1) != -1 ){
            idxs[0] = i;

          }
        }

          return idxs;

      }

      hideInfo(){
        $('.choices, .scores').fadeOut();

      }

      init(){
        //player gives choice
        player.getPlayerInput();
        //computer gives choice
        computer.getComputerInput();
        //choices are compared
        game.compareInput();
        //fade out winner/loser divs
        $('.winner, .loser').fadeOut();
      }

      newRound(){

        $('.choices, .scores').fadeIn();

        player.getPlayerInput();
        //computer gives choice
        computer.getComputerInput();
        //choices are compared
        game.compareInput();
      }

      checkWinner(pscore,cscore){

        if (pscore === 3) {
          $('.winlose').html("You are the final game winner!");
          $('.winner').fadeIn();
        } else if (cscore === 3){
          $('.winlose').html("The computer is the final game winner!");
          $('.loser').fadeIn();
        }

        $('.instruct').fadeOut();
      }


}

let game = new Game();
let player = new Player();
let computer = new Player();



game.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This part:

> ```
>     let choice = event.target.dataset.tag;
>
>     switch (choice) {
>         case "rock":
>             this.choice = "rock";
>             break;
>         case "scissors":
>             this.choice = "scissors";
>             break;
>         case "paper":
>             this.choice = "paper";
>             break;
>      }
> ```

is redundant. It could be just `this.choice = event.target.dataset.tag;`

- You can also simplify the `getComputerInput` to something like:

  ```
  return ["rock", "paper", "scissors"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  ```

  It makes more sense because a random number here is essentially an array index.
- The`compareInput` function is huge and does a lot things at the same time. You can make it more manageable by separating it into different logical parts (with a separate function for each of them): one part should just compute the winner given two strings, and the other one should make the updates based on it (like changing the score and showing the winner).

Answer (score 2):

Granted I'm no javascript expert at all, but here are my 2 cents.

You have a huge `switch-statement` where you check who wins based on the chosen move from both `Computer` and `Player`,

That check would be so much simpler if you stored the different possible outcomes in an `object`.

That same object would make a lot of your other `switches` and `if-statements` a lot cleaner as well

Here is a short example of how this could be done;

```
//Object containing the possible outcomes
// 1    ->      win
// 0    ->      tied
// -1   ->      loose
const rps = {
    rock : { rock: 0, paper: -1, scissor: 1 },
    paper : { rock: 1, paper: 0, scissor: -1 }, 
    scissor: { rock: -1, paper: 1, scissor: 0 }
};


//Array for a computer to choise randomly from
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];


//Chose one of the three values randomly
const computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

//Ask player for choice
const playerCoice = prompt("Rock paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();

//pass those values to the object to get either 1, 0, - 1 back 
const result = rps[playerCoice][computerChoice];

//Which you then use to determine the winner.
const winner = (result === 1) ? "Player" :
                (result === 0) ? "Tied" : 
                "Computer";

document.write("Player chose: " + playerCoice + "<br>");
document.write("Computer chose: " + computerChoice + "<br><br>");
document.write("The winner is " + winner);
```